# getting ETIMEDOUT err on installing npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Here is the error which I am getting on installing npm packages, I have uninstalled node from my windows and again installed but still getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ch Wasiq\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T07_38_36_764Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you work behind of a company proxy?

Comment: @norbitrial noo! , I am learning nodejs just installed node on my windows and getting this error in terminal.

Comment: Try once with some other network...

Comment: @piyush Bro...I wont get what you are sayimg,,how can i try someanother  network

Comment: I mean if you are using broadband connection, so try once with USB wired network or Mobile hotspot. as most of the time this issue is due to network only

Comment: Yes, confirmed i am also getting same error for all type of packages, even npm web page is also not available. Tried on Broadband connection then from 4G connection.

Comment: @NaumanRafique Bro here in my browser npm's webpage is opening but on installing npm packages i am getting above error?